# An ambiguity in the relativistic velocity addition

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, inertial-frames

Imagine a car $S'$ with a velocity $ v = c $ in the +x direction. Now if someone fires a photon from the back of the car opposite to it's the direction of motion, that is $ u = -c $. Using the velocity addition formula, the velocity of photon observed by a stationary observer is

$$ u' = \frac{u + v}{1+\frac{uv}{c^2}} $$

here, $ u = -c $ and $ v = c $. The value of $ u' $ is

$$ u' = \frac{-c + c}{1-\frac{c^2}{c^2}} $$
$$ u' = \frac{0}{0} $$

What does this physically mean? Does it imply that we can never reach the velocity of a photon?

Comment: "Imagine a car with $v=c$".... no way, the car has certainly some mass...

Comment: Your question starts with an incorrect premise, that the source is moving with speed c. That's outside the valid context.  When you pose questions, be sure that your beginning point has validity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, discovering a 0/0 means that you've broken some assumption that you didn't realize you were making.  One tool for figuring out what's happened is taking limits, which here requires [L'Hôptial's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) since the fraction misbehaves.

If we start with $v=c$ then we get

$$
\lim_{u\to -c} \frac{u+c}{1+uc/c^2}
=
\lim_{u\to -c} \frac{1}{c/c^2}
= +c
$$

But if we start with $u=-c$ and take the limit on the other variable, we get

$$
\lim_{v\to c} \frac{-c + v}{1 - cv/c^2}
=
\lim_{v\to c} \frac{1}{-c/c^2}
= -c
$$

You ask

> What does this physically mean? Does it imply that we can never reach the velocity of a photon?

to which the answer is yes, you nailed it.  If you're traveling at $v<c$, no matter how close you get, you can't outrun a photon. Photons reaching you from ahead or from behind reach you with speed $c$, and photons you emit leave you with speed $c$ whether they're in your forward or your backward direction.  This is one of the most important results in relativity.

What if both particles are massive but relativistic?  Then we can let

$$ u = -c(1-\epsilon), \qquad v = c(1-\delta)$$

and get

\begin{align}
u' &= \frac{u + v}{1 + uv/c^2}
\\ &= \frac{-(1-\epsilon)+(1-\delta)}{1 - (1-\epsilon)(1-\delta)} c
\\&= \frac{\epsilon-\delta}{\epsilon+\delta-\text{small}} c
\end{align}

So for massive particles the faster one does win, but the relative speed is inflated by a factor $1/(\epsilon+\delta)$ which we assumed was large.

Comment: Brilliiant answer, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not put $v=c$ and $u=-c$ both together in the velocity addition formula. It suffices to insert $u=-c$ to get:

$$u'=\frac{-c+v}{1-vc/c^2}=c\frac{-c+v}{c-v}=-c\space.$$

I just wonder why the result is otherwise if we first choose $v=c$:

$$u'=\frac{u+c}{1+uc/c^2}=c\frac{u+c}{c+u}=c\space(!)$$

**Added according to @rob 's answer:**

Substituting $u=-x$, $v=y$, $c=1$ and $u'=f(x,y)$, we can rewrite the velocity addition formula as a Cartisian two-variable function:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{y-x}{1-xy}\space.$$

This function, however, has an odd behavior around point $(x,y)=(1,1)$. That is, if we use the final part of @rob's calculation, we obtain different results for different paths along which we approach point $(1,1)$. Assume $\epsilon=2\delta$, then we have:

$$u'=\frac{\epsilon-\delta}{\epsilon+\delta}c=\frac{\delta}{3\delta}c=\frac{c}{3}\space.$$

If we choose $\epsilon=5\delta$, we get:

$$u'=\frac{\epsilon-\delta}{\epsilon+\delta}c=\frac{4\delta}{6\delta}c=\frac{2c}{3}\space,$$

and so on. Therefore, it seems that it is not possible to determine $u'$ by knowing that $v$ and $u$ approach $c$, but rather we have to know *how* and to what *speed* they approach $c$, otherwise we have an infinite number of answers! I must confess that this result is slightly odd to me.

Comment: This seems more like "I also have the same question" than like an answer. But here's an interpretation. You're traveling to the right at $v$ and emitting particles to the left at $-|u|$. As long as $|u|<|v|$, or equivalently $\epsilon>\delta$, I will see your emitted particles still moving to the right. Furthermore, unless $\epsilon \approx \delta$, the emitted particle is still relativistic in my rest frame, no matter which way it's moving.  The limit where $\epsilon\gg\delta$ is $u'/c \approx 1-2\delta/\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a universe where the effect of a continuous transition to higher and higher speeds on the coordinates x and t is given infinitesimally by

δx = -βυt,
δt = -αυx.

Transitions to frames moving at different speeds are called **boosts**, and this is an expression for an **infinitesimal** boost: υ.

Applying this to a trajectory given by x = vt produces

-βυt = δx = δ(vt) = δv t + v δt = δv t - v αυ(vt)

or

δv = αυv² - βυ.

Of the five different possibilities: α=0=β, α=0&β≠0, α≠0&β=0, αβ<0, αβ>0, the two that are most familiar are those that arise from Galileo (α=0&β≠0), for the non-Relativistic universe, and Poincaré/Lorentz/Einstein (αβ>0) for the Relativistic universe.

You can continuously transform to higher speeds by treating this as a continuous variation with respect to a parameter χ - which we'll call **rapidity** - by defining υ = δχ. Then the equations for the infinitesimal transform become differential equations:

dx/dχ = -βt,
dt/dχ = -αx

and, thus,

dv/dχ = αv² - β.

This can be integrated, the simplest way being to directly integrate for the coordinates first; and this, in turn, can be done by writing the equations as second order equations with initial conditions as follows:

d²x/dχ² = αβx, x(0) = x, x'(0) = -βt;
d²t/dχ² = αβt, t(0) = t, t'(0) = -αx.

Thus, it follows that

x(χ) = x cs(αβ,χ) - βt sn(αβ,χ)
t(χ) = t cs(αβ,χ) - αx sn(αβ,χ)

and, upon substitution of x(χ) by v(χ) t(χ) and x by v t:

v(χ) = (v - β tn(αβ,χ))/(1 - αv tn(αβ,χ))

The functions

cs(γ,x) = 1 + γ x²/2! + γ² x⁴/4! + γ³ x⁶/6! + ⋯,
sn(γ,x) = x + γ x³/3! + γ² x⁵/5! + γ³ x⁷/7! + ⋯,

and

tn(γ,x) = sn(γ,x)/cs(γ,x)

depend on the sign of γ = αβ and are given by:

cs(γ,x) = cosh(√γ x), sn(γ,x) = sinh(√γ x)/√γ, tn(γ,x) = tanh(√γ x)/√γ, if γ > 0;
cs(γ,x) = 1, sn(γ,x) = x, tn(γ,x) = x, if γ = 0;
cs(γ,x) = cos(√-γ x), sn(γ,x) = sin(√-γ x)/√-γ, tn(γ,x) = tan(√-γ x)/√-γ, if γ < 0.

For the non-Relativistic universe, α=0&β≠0, this produces the continuous transition

v → v(χ) = v - βχ = v - u

and the corresponding boost velocity u = βχ can be continuously changed without bound.

For the Relativistic universe, αβ > 0, this produces the continuous transition

v(χ) = (v - β/√(αβ) tanh(√(αβ) χ))/(1 - α/√(αβ) v tanh(√(αβ) χ))

and the corresponding boost velocity u = β/√(αβ) tanh(√(αβ) χ) is limited to speeds in the range |u| < √(β/α); no continuous transition can get it past that bound. The corresponding formula, expressed in terms of u, is

v(χ) = (v - u)/(1 - α/β uv),

so, if the limiting speed is defined as c ≡ √(β/α), then it follows that the transition is that given by

v → v(χ) = (v - u)/(1 - uv/c²); only for |u| < c.

The speed v can be taken as anything, since this transform applies to *all* world-lines x = vt, regardless of what v is. But the boost speed |u| is strictly limited by |u| < c.

(In fact, you can even apply it to |v| = ∞ - i.e. to the worldline t = 0 - in which case you get v → v(χ) = -c²/u; for |u| < c; thus showing that the "speed of simultaneity" transforms to a finite super-luminal velocity. Likewise, all velocities v with super-luminal speeds |v| > c, have a transform to the speed of simultaneity given by a boost u = +c²/v.)

Velocities v = ±c whose speeds are light speed, |v| = c, transform to the same:

v → v(χ) = (±c - u)/(1 ∓ u/c) = ±c.

For the Galilean case, in contrast, it's the speed of simultaneity |v| = ∞ which remains invariant: the worldline t = 0 is invariant under Galilean transforms.

The case α=0&β≠0 corresponds to the limit c → ∞, while the case α≠0&β=0 corresponds to the limit c → 0. Most interestingly, the case α=0=β, which corresponds to applying *both* limits c → ∞ *and* c → 0 together at the same time, is also consistent!

Noteworthy is that in all the cases β=0, it's the world-line x = 0, and the velocity v = 0 which remains invariant; while non-zero velocities transform as

v → v(χ) = v/(1 - αχv).

All finite non-zero velocities in this universe are super-luminal and each such velocity v, where |v| > 0, has a transition to (or from) the speed of simultaneity given by the rapidity χ = 1/(αv), in the case α≠0&β=0. That's the "Carrollian" universe, named after Lewis Carroll because stationary things run in place and never move.

The velocities are invariant only in the extreme case α=0=β - the "static" universe.

Finally, the case αβ < 0 corresponds to x and t being dimensions of the same type (both spatial or both temporal), in which case, the transition formulae on x and t become that for circular rotation.

Comment: Welcome to [physics.se]! Note most users use [MathJax](http://mathjax.org) to typeset mathematics; there's [brief help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) and [extended help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166791) available to get you started.